# Why is this solution for the final problem of the HMMT (Harvard MIT Math Tournament) incorrect?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question in question is this:

> A continuous real function $f$ satisfies the identity $f(2x) = 3 f(x)$ for all $x$. If $\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx= 1$, what is $\int_1^2 f(x) \,dx$?

**The correct solution for this is 5.**

For this, I decided to use the following method:

$$\int_1^2 f(x) \,dx= \int_ \frac12^1 3f(x) \,dx = 3\int_ \frac12^1 f(x) \,dx$$

$$\int_ \frac12^1 f(x) \,dx = 3\int_ \frac14^{\frac12} f(x) \,dx = 9\int_ \frac18^{\frac14} f(x) \,dx  ...$$

Letting  $\int_ \frac12^1 f(x) \,dx = S $,

$$1 = S + \frac13 S + \frac19 S + \frac1{27}S + ... $$

By using the formula for geometric progression to find a sum to infinity, $\frac{a}{1-r}$,

$$1 = \frac{S}{\frac23} = \frac32S$$
$$S = \frac23$$
$$\int_1^2 f(x) \,dx= 3\int_ \frac12^1 f(x) \,dx = 3S = 3 \cdot \frac23 = 2$$

**Using my method, the answer is 2. However, the correct answer is 5.**

If anybody could help my figure out the logical error in my solution, it will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The first equation in your computation is wrong by a factor $2$. (I haven't checked for further errors.)

Comment: The problem is with your use of change of variable theorem, because if you do $x=2t$ then $dx=2dt$. The $f(2t)=3f(t)$ is made before the change of variable, so you cannot eliminate the $2$ that multiplies the integral due the change of variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here

> $$\int_1^2 f(x) \,dx= \int_ \frac12^1 3f(x) \,dx = 3\int_ \frac12^1 f(x) \,dx$$

You should be more careful with your substitutions. The correct result is
$$
\int_1^2 f(x) \,dx= 2\int_ \frac12^1 f(2u) \,du = 6\int_ \frac12^1 f(u) \,du
$$
and similarly for the other integrals. This means your series is
$$
1 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{S}{6^i} = \frac{S}{1-\frac{1}{6}} = \frac{6}{5}S
$$
and that leads to
$$
\int_1^2 f(x) \,dx= 6S = 5.
$$

Answer (score 5):

There is also a easier way to solve it:
We have $f(2x)=3f(x)$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=1$. So $\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}f(2x)dx=1$. Make $2x=t$, so $\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{2}f(t)dt=1$. It implies that $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{1}^{2}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx=6$$, so $$\int_{1}^{2}f(x)dx=6-1=5$$

Comment: The fact that $f(2x)=3f(x)$ does not affect the fact that if we take $x=2t$ the small variations of $x$ , i.e. $dx$ is equal to $2dt$, so we first plug in our integral the change of variable with the $2dt$ and then whe use the fact that $f(2t)=3f(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is of the form $f(x)=cx^a,$ $x\ge 0,$ where $a=\log_23.$ Thus
$${\int\limits_1^2cx^a\,dx\over \int\limits_0^1cx^a\,dx}=2^{a+1}-1=2\cdot 3-1=5$$

Comment: Why is $f$ necessarily of that form?